# Twitter feed Continuous data collection with intermittent updates

Tags: python, twitter, nltk, tweepy

I'm collecting the twitter data. I filter the stream by the specified term, 'birthday'. I want to be able to count the frequencies, concurrently with the data collection, without interrupting it.
Now it is just printing everything.

**If I were to create another function def data_processing() which would count the word frequencies, how can I access z= nltk.word_tokenize(extracted) from  def on_data(self, data) ?**

```
    import tweepy
    import json
    import nltk
    import time

    # counting
    import numpy
    from collections import Counter



    # Authentication details. To  obtain these visit dev.twitter.com

    consumer_key = XXX
    consumer_secret = XXX
    access_token = XXX
    access_token_secret = XXX
    sequence=[]

    # This is the listener, resposible for receiving data
    class StdOutListener(tweepy.StreamListener):



    def on_data(self, data):
     # Twitter returns data in JSON format - we need to decode it first
    decoded = json.loads(data)


    # Also, we convert UTF-8 to ASCII ignoring all bad characters sent         by users
   decoded['text'].encode('latin1', 'ignore')))

            extracted=decoded['text'].encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
            z= nltk.word_tokenize(extracted)


                    print(z)
            return True


    if __name__ == '__main__':

        l = StdOutListener()
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

        print ("Showing all new tweets for #programming:")

        # There are different kinds of streams: public stream, user stream, multi-user streams
        # In this example follow #programming tag
        # For more details refer to https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis
        stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, l, timeout=60)
        stream.filter(track=['birthday'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You `print` in the `on_data` function.

So of course it will print every time it receives data.

Instead, remove the `print`, wait until your 5 minutes are over, stop the stream, and print after the stream has stopped.

Comment: Sorry, I read your question as if you wanted to stop, and work with a 5 minute sample only. Then don't stop, just print.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
import time
time.sleep(5*60)
```

to pause the execution for 5 minutes